# Word for a person who likes to argue

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

I recently read somewhere a single word that described a person who enjoyed an argument - in the sense of a lively debate. It may have been a word implying a positive or neutral context but I don't think it was negative or derogatory.

A complex word (uncommon in colloquial use), medium length (7-8 letters), possibly ending in -ic. *One or more of these points may be a false memory.*

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Polemic*** ***(polemicist)*** or ***Controversialist***.

> *polemic (noun):* A person who argues or writes in opposition to another, or who takes up a controversial position; a controversialist. Cf. polemicist *n.* [OED]
>
> *polemicist (noun):* An author of polemics; a controversialist. [OED]
>
> ---
>
> *controversialist (noun):* a person who likes to disagree with other people and say things that make people angry or think about a subject [[Cambridge]](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/controversialist)

---

You can consider ***argumentative*** or ***contentious*** as an adjective.

Comment: Bravo! "Polemic" was the word I was looking for - though having looked at the definition I'm less sure of the implied context. Would you say it's context is positive, negative or neutral?

Comment: @kaben: It would be negative because they harshly criticize people.

Answer (score 5):

> [**debater**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/debater)
>    a person who disputes; who is good at or enjoys controversy
>
> **eristic**
>   2. a person who engages in disputation
>   the art or practice or debate or argument
>
> [**gainsay**](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/gainsay)
>   Gainsay comes from an Old English word that means "contradict" or "say against," 
>   If you know someone who constantly corrects others, tells them that they're wrong, and says, "That's not true," more than anyone else, you have first-hand experience with the art of the gainsay.

<sub>The Free Dictionary. Vocabulary.com</sub>

Comment: master debater.

Answer (score 4):

"Contrarian" is a good term for someone who always has to bring up a contrary point. I like it because it is neutral, even though the behavior itself can be quite annoying. The noun form gives it dignity, as if there's an important role a contrarian plays in a group.

Answer (score 1):

How about ***antagonistic***? Or maybe, ***pugnacious***.

Comment: Those are adjectives not nouns.

Comment: @JimiOke, I don't see the question asking for nouns specifically...?

Answer (score 0):

***contentious, quarrelsome, cantankerous, O.E. contekors, [grizzle guts](https://books.google.ca/books?id=4J5Fo7OSfXgC&pg=PT593&dq=quarrelsome%20slang&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nGopVY12t4CxBPq4gLgH&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=quarrelsome%20slang&f=false), obstructive, argol-bargolous, quarrelsome; argy-bargy (—1887) [is mostly Scottish], scolding; ill- natured, disputatious, [boiler (sl)](https://books.google.ca/books?id=5GpLcC4a5fAC&pg=PA149&dq=quarrelsome%20slang&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2GspVZL7BMmIsQSau4DgBg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=quarrelsome%20slang&f=false)***

Answer (score -1):

Some good answers here but just wanted to add **devil's advocate** - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil%27s_advocate

Answer (score -2):

The best noun I've ever heard, was in a star trek episode, where Kirk refers to Harry as an 'irritant'.

**Irritant** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irritant)

> something that is unpleasant or annoying : something that irritates you
>
> *"dust and other lung irritants"*
> *"The delay was a minor irritant."*