# how do you describe someone who enjoys intellectual arguments?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a term that describes someone who enjoys intellectual arguments, e.g. how physicists would like debating about theories they're working with or how people enjoy arguing over the meaning of a literary text? For example,

> This student in my class is ____ - they get along with others while stimulating discussion.

Everything I've found so far seems to have negative connotations. Is there any word that has neutral or positive connotations?

Comment: Related: [Word for a person who likes to argue](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/238750/word-for-a-person-who-likes-to-argue)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a ***DEBATER***.
It doesn't have any negative connotation.

It is often used with 'great' and other 'positive' adjectives.

According to Oxford Living Dictionary:

***debater***

A person who argues about a subject, especially in a formal manner.

‘he is a skilled debater and has a deep command of the issues’

‘As Gould once noted, the truth is only one weapon, seldom the best, in a debater's arsenal.’

‘Success will hang on the debaters' ability to exploit this divisive topic.’

‘His prowess as a skilful debater in Parliament is also well known.’

‘He's been a very effective debater in the past.’

‘He is also a brilliant orator and a superb debater.’

‘As a platform speaker and debater he had few equals in a land of fluent speakers.’

‘He became known as a superb speaker, a witty panellist, and a persuasive debater.'