# What is a word ending in -phile that means somebody who likes arguing

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

I'm sure there must be one. I need it for a rhyme.

Comment: There are lots of words for people who love to argue in the answers to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/238750/word-for-a-person-who-likes-to-argue), but none ending in "phile". It would be an interesting question to ask when the suffix "phile" is used, but it doesn't normally refer to something mundane, such as arguing - it has more of an aura of medical terminology or intellectual sophistication.

Comment: If you're after a rhyme not a "-phile", [Macmillan's thesaurus](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/words-used-to-describe-people-who-are-quick-to-argue) suggests "volatile"

Comment: Thanks, Stuart. That's not a bad op.

Comment: The trouble is that *-phile* is of Greek origin, which calls for something of Greek origin to be the first part of the word, and the obvious choice would be *logo-*, leading one to *logophile*. That word, however, cannot be used for this purpose, because it is, in English, already taken for a different one.

Comment: If you wanted to coin a new word from Greek roots (which could work in the right humorous context), you could try "eridophile" from *eris* "discord" or "nicophile"/"neicophile" (both forms would be philologically plausible) from *neikos* "argument". (Although the Internet informs me that *nicophile* has a meaning in French, as "collector of cigarette packages"!)

Comment: -phile is more often used to refer to someone who is attracted to something, not as much for participating in an activity. So if there were a -phile word for this, it would probably mean someone who likes to read or watch arguments, not someone who likes to argue.

Comment: For instance, a bibliophile is someone who likes books, but not necessarily a writer or publisher.

Comment: It should be made clear whether you have in mind somebody who likes arguing as a way of finding out the truth, **or** somebody who likes arguing as a game, without much regard for the truth. If the latter, then the comment by Mr. Harris may be on the right track.

Comment: @ConnorHarris There is [***eristic***](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/eristic).